# Autocommit and Spring Declarative Transactions

Tags: hibernate, spring, hibernate-mapping

I have a single service method annotated with `Propagation.Required`. It performs three separate operations .

1. Insert to table 1  from table z if no records are in table 1
2. Insert/Update table 1 as per user edits/Additions
3. Delete x records from table 1

Forgive my ignorance but shouldn't all these run under a single transaction ? In the sense, if the third Query runs into an Exception, shouldn't the first & second rollback too ? This doesn't happen in my case. Will hibernate auto commit setting affect the txn boundaries in any way ? Auto commit is set to true in my case. What I require is the commit should take place in any of these tables only if all are successful.

Comment: We have no chance of answering you without seeing your code and your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Hibernate `connection.autocommit` property setting will affect transaction boundaries.

If you set this to `true`, Hibernate will put the underlying JDBC connection in autocommit mode, which will wrap each statement you execute in its own database transaction.

So, for example, if your third query/statement fails, only your third query/statement will get rolled back.

To execute all three as a single unit, you need to have autocommit off and execute all three in the context of a single transaction, declarative or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

could you try to add one more layer higher than service layer and start transaction from there.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want autocommit on. That will probably commit after every operation. Switch autocommit off, and add an explicit commit at the end.